# What does "fudge on something" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

I've come across in the 13th episode of the 7th season of *The Office*. Here is the context:

> Pam: But that’s okay. Because it’s not about being perfect, it’s about trying. In fact, why don’t we go around and confess some of the ways that we’ve **fudged** **on** some of our resolutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the verb "fudge", so let's check the dictionary...

(from lexico):  present or deal with (something) in a vague or inadequate way, especially so as to conceal the truth or mislead.

Resolutions are probably New Years Resolutions: promises that we make to ourselves to be "better" in the New Year.

If you fudge on a resolution you don't really keep it.  For example if you resolve to stop smoking, but decide that cigarettes after 5pm "don't count".... you are fudging your resolution.